# Identify the distribution/family of a variable

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model

I have this distribution for my response variable that I want to use to build a model with a binary matrix as predictor variable. I think to use glm to do this, but I don't know which family to use, since my response variable is not normally or poisson distributed and it's a continuous variable between 0 and 1. Also I want to know if in this case glm is the right choice to do this (the scope of my analysis is to study the coefficients of the generated model).

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very little to build on to give advice, but search this site for *beta regression*